# XPath expression to check for attribute values across multiple child nodes

Tags: xml, xpath

Given the XML below, I am looking for an XPath query to answer the following question:

Does the language list described by the XML above contain all of these languages: "English", "French" and "Norwegian"?

In other words, is there a way to find out if the "Entities" node contains a given set of languages? The answer would be TRUE for "English", "French" and "Norwegian", but FALSE for "Arabic", "English", "French" and "Norwegian".

```
<Document>
  <Entities>
    <Entity Name="Afrikaans" Id="2000" Type="Language"/>
    <Entity Name="Dansk" Id="2002" Type="Language"/>
    <Entity Name="Deutsch" Id="2003" Type="Language"/>
    <Entity Name="English" Id="2005" Type="Language"/>
    <Entity Name="Español" Id="2006" Type="Language"/>
    <Entity Name="French" Id="2007" Type="Language"/>
    <Entity Name="Indonesian" Id="2010" Type="Language"/>
    <Entity Name="Italiano" Id="2012" Type="Language"/>
    <Entity Name="Norwegian" Id="2018" Type="Language"/>
  </Entities>
</Document>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using XPath 2.0, the `exists()` function returns `true` or `false`...

```
exists(/*/Entities[*/@Name='English' and */@Name='French' and */@Name='Norwegian'])
```

Comment: This did the job for me. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This XPath

```
/Document/Entities/Entity[@Name='Norwegian'] and /Document/Entities/Entity[@Name='French'] and /Document/Entities/Entity[@Name='English']
```

will be `true` if all three languages are there and `false` otherwise

Answer (score 0):

**In XPath 1.0 use**:

```
  /*/*/Entity/@Name = 'English'
and
  /*/*/Entity/@Name = 'French'
and
  /*/*/Entity/@Name = 'Norwegian'
```

**In XPath 2.0 use**:

```
 every $lang in ('English', 'French', 'Norwegian')
   satisfies
       $lang = /*/*/Entity/@Name
```

Comment: DevNull, Mimo, Dimitre: Thanks to all of you for your answers. I just wanted to let you know that I am still experimenting with your suggestions. Being fairly new to XPath/XQuery, it's taking me a little longer than usual. I am intrigued by XPath 2.0 and will likely end up using it instead of XPath 1.0 for the wealth of syntactic sugar it comes with. I have download Saxon, but so far haven't found an equivalent of XmlDocument.SelectNodes(<xpath_expression>) in the Saxon API. Once I have my prototype working, I will come back and mark one of your posts as an answer. Thanks again!